# How can potassium rich foods reduce blood pressure?

Tags: health, blood-pressure

How come sodium increases blood pressure, but potassium, which has to some extent similar properties helps lower it?

Answer (score -1):

potassium is really the main guy in charge of everything that happens involving action potentials which in turn govern homeostasis such as blood pressure.

k+ lowers blood pressure due to making it harder to get an action potential going, which in the macro scale causes the heart to pump less.

too much k+ kills the person as it stops the pumping of blood (lethal injections are just lots and lots of k+ along with some pain killing drugs)

Comment: This provides some information but does not fully answer the question. Why is $K^+$ the main "guy" rather than $Na^+$.  The question assumes that they have similar properties. In what ways relevant to the question are these two ions different?

Comment: I agree with @vkehayas but I'd go a step further to say that this answer is completely wrong as far as the mechanisms for what the OP is asking about. We aren't talking about lethal injection levels of K+ or anything about K+ concentration effects on action potentials when talking about K+ effects on blood pressure.